# itunesconnect not showing the prerelease build

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode6.3

1) I'm achieving the build using Xcode 6.3.

2) After Successful validation submitting the build to app store for beta testing.

Xcode is showing the status "submitted successfully".

The issues is, The build is not visible in itunesconnect under prerelease tab.

I checked the version. Version number in not same. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Is there any issue with Xcode 6.3 or iTunesconnect.

Comment: Is it visible under *Builds*?

Comment: No it is not visible. Tried for 2 days.

Comment: I mean *Builds* in the main page of your app.

Comment: Hello Linus G. , No I mean under prerelease -> builds section. Now it started showing up. suddenly. I faced this problem for 2 days. Now its working fine. But couldn't find the reason.

Comment: @Ganesh, the most probable reason is the incompetence of the developers who coded the platform. I've had a lot of issues recently when trying to publish a prerelease build.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I just uploaded the binary again and now it showed up in prerelease.